# How to resolve following key error in the my code while manipulating dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have this data frame. here i want to match a date value and will compare if at this current index and at next index employee id is same or not if they are same then i want to delete the row at next index. i tried with below code but getting key error:1

| EMPL_ID | AGE | EMPLOYER | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 23 | BHU | 2022-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 12 | 21 | BHU | 2022-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 34 | 22 | DU | 2022-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 36 | 21 | BHU | 2022-04-22 00:00:00 |

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  value = row['END_DATE']
  if (value == '2022-04-22 00:00:00'):
     a = index
     if (df.loc[a, 'EMPL_ID'] == df.loc[a+1, 'EMPL_ID']):
         df.drop(a+1, inplace = True)
     else:
       df = df
  else:
    df = df
```

Comment: the issue is that in the first iteration of your `for` loop you delete the `1`-index row, but then in the next iteration you are trying to use the `1`-index. It can cause errors to loop through a df while modifying it

Answer (score 0):

Keeping only the unique values based on two columns can be performed using the function drop_duplicates, while supplying the columns that make up the subset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3, 3], 'time': [1, 2, 3, 3]})
>>> df

   id  time
0   1     1
1   2     2
2   3     3
3   3     3

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'time'], inplace=True)
>>> df

   id  time
0   1     1
1   2     2
2   3     3
```

Comment: If I understood the task right, he doesn't just want to drop all duplicates. Only drop them if the duplicates are in consecutive rows.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC here is one approach. Since you only search for consecutive duplicates I added another row to your example. The 2nd row of "EMPL_ID" `34` won't be deleted.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EMPL_ID': [12, 12, 34, 36, 34],
 'AGE': [23, 21, 22, 21, 22],
 'EMPLOYER': ['BHU', 'BHU', 'DU', 'BHU', 'DU'],
 'END_DATE': ['2022-04-22 00:00:00','2022-04-22 00:00:00','2022-04-22 00:00:00','2022-04-22 00:00:00','2022-04-22 00:00:00'],
})

print(df)
   EMPL_ID  AGE EMPLOYER             END_DATE
0       12   23      BHU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
1       12   21      BHU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
2       34   22       DU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
3       36   21      BHU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
4       34   22       DU  2022-04-22 00:00:00

grp = ['END_DATE', 'EMPL_ID']
df['group'] = (df[grp] != df[grp].shift(1)).any(axis=1).cumsum()
df = df.drop_duplicates('group', keep= 'first').drop('group', axis=1)

print(df)
   EMPL_ID  AGE EMPLOYER             END_DATE
0       12   23      BHU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
2       34   22       DU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
3       36   21      BHU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
4       34   22       DU  2022-04-22 00:00:00
```